What folders can I put a shortcut in where Windows 11 will allow the hotkey?
I created a shortcut to a Word document in My Documents. (Both were in that folder).
I created a hotkey for that shortcut. It doesn't work.
I then moved the shortcut to the Desktop. Still doesn't work.
I've read that Windows 11 doesn't allow shortcuts from certain folders.

https://github.com/AutoHotkey/AutoHotkey/releases is what I use anytime I need windows keyboard commands.
